# What type of this time filed

Tags: c#

I found these details from a column named `"Date Stamp"` in a database (.mdb).

It shows `131203858`. On software UI i see it as `03/18/2002`.

I'm not sure what type of date time is this `(131203858)`, and I am trying to figure it out so that I can use it in my new program.

Essentially I am trying to figure out the proper type for datetime that the database is currently using, so that I can make use of it in the next program I write.

Below are some more records to compare.

`131203858: 03/18/2002,
131203860: 03/20/2002,
131203861: 03/21/2002`

Comment: The number seems a day counter, but the numbers are more than the number of days since 1/1/0001

Comment: @ShaiCohen Are you sure?

Comment: What type of database is it?

Comment: it an Access db (.mdb)

Comment: Well, if it actually _is_ a day counter of some kind, you could take that number, subtract 130472932 from it, then take the result and set it as the number of days since 1/1/0001. =D

Comment: @WillRay thanks, but it not work for all.

Answer (score 2):

I Finally fig out what kind of these data.

> 131203858: 03/18/2002

it mean 131203858 = (2002 * 65536) + (18 * 256) + 03
Thanks everyone for support.